# Edit the stylesheet of a child theme

Tags: plugins, html, css

I'm using the free "responsive" theme, as a child theme

How can I change the CSS stylesheet? As it not working by the usual way by using the editor

Thanks!!

Comment: By editing the style.css file. What's not working about the editor? You can also edit the file via FTP.

Comment: Are you using the 'Responsive' theme **as** a child theme? Or, are you using a child theme **of** the 'Responsive' theme? As @JacobPeattie has asked too, why is the editor not working for you? (and by the editor, I am assuming you mean the editor under 'Appearance' -> 'Editor'?)

Comment: Could you also provide a link to your website?

Comment: I installed the themre by downloading a rar file from here: https://wordpress.org/themes/responsive/

the link to my website:

http://ampmdoorservices.ca/

and yes, I'm trying to edit via Appearance -> Editor